How may I solve this?
darksoul@Ronits-MacBook-Air ~ % create-react-app --version
5.0.1
darksoul@Ronits-MacBook-Air ~ % react --version
zsh: command not found: react
darksoul@Ronits-MacBook-Air ~ % node --v
node: bad option: --v
darksoul@Ronits-MacBook-Air ~ % node -v 
v22.12.0
darksoul@Ronits-MacBook-Air ~ % create-react-app hello

Creating a new React app in /Users/darksoul/hello.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


added 1314 packages in 38s

261 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: hello@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error /Users/darksoul/.npm/_logs/2024-12-06T07_30_06_577Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/darksoul/.npm/_logs/2024-12-06T07_30_06_577Z-debug-0.log
`npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed
darksoul@Ronits-MacBook-Air ~ % node -v
v22.12.0
darksoul@Ronits-MacBook-Air ~ % npm -v
10.9.0
darksoul@Ronits-MacBook-Air ~ % npx -v
10.9.0
darksoul@Ronits-MacBook-Air ~ % 

I tried ChatGPT and Gemini but No Work. I didn't changed any configuration and was working on this for last 2years. But When I was creating a new app yesterday I got this error

The obligatory "Don't use create-react-app" comment: It's not recommend to be used for at least 2 years and didn't get updates for a long time.

Use command create-react-app  as usual. Then after you've got errors due React 19, delete folder node_modules and files package.json and package-lock.json.
After that, add files package.json and package-lock.json from archive below - these files are backup versions from when last stable was React 18.3.1
After that, run command npm install
You'll get working React 18.3.1 App as before)
_package.json package-lock.json backup cra React18 - OK
Mirror - _package.json package-lock.json backup cra React18 - OK
